# Code to make photos appear after a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for code that makes photos appear after a certain amount of time on a site. this the code i want to be appear a certain amount of time on a site:

```
<div style="float:left;"><a href="https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase?sid=1401348&quantity=1&product_id=8" rel="nofollow""><img src="http://www.interestingquestionstoaskagirl.msl37.org/wp-content/esg7/m-12.gif" title="" width="148" height="25" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-155" /></a></div>
<div style="float:right;"><a href="http://www.msl37.org/wp-content/d/5.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://www.interestingquestionstoaskagirl.msl37.org/wp-content/esg7/kas-34.jpg" title="" width="148" height="25" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-160" /></a></div>
```

i'm not experienced with JavaScript or web developing put i hope you can help me.
**thanks on advance**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this way (demo => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/EqZ88/):

wrap that HTML inside a wrapper div i.e.

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div style="float:left;"><a href="https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase?sid=1401348&quantity=1&product_id=8" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://www.interestingquestionstoaskagirl.msl37.org/wp-content/esg7/m-12.gif" title="" width="148" height="25" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-155" /></a></div>
    <div style="float:right;"><a href="http://www.msl37.org/wp-content/d/5.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://www.interestingquestionstoaskagirl.msl37.org/wp-content/esg7/kas-34.jpg" title="" width="148" height="25" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-160" /></a></div>

</div>
```

and then add this css rule

```
#wrapper{
    display:none; /*wrapper and its content does not appear when user loads the page */
}
```

finally, by javascript, make them appearing after some seconds (5 i.e.)

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('wrapper').style.display = "block";
},5000);
```

p.s. there's one more `"` at the end of the first `a` element in your markup

Comment: hey man, it really works like a charm in a HTML pages, but it seems not to be working on WP page (i guess because the JavaScript), would you please help me solve this problem. thanks on advance.

Comment: hey man, it works like a charm in a HTML pages, but it seems not to be working on WP page (i guess because the JavaScript), i tried some WP plugin to run Java on WP ( plugin called AYB Javascript In Posts ) but it did not work, i also tried to use this code <script type=”text/javascript src=”http://www.your-domain-name.com/scripts/my-javascript.js”></script> to include the java text but it did not work too would you please help me solve this problem.

Comment: have u put the code after the markup? (it s always javascript and not java ;))